Question about word (relationship between language and thought)
Can you think anything without word ?
Can you think any word without thought ?
Which comes first word or thought ?

+1 Excellent question not in the database! Feel free to roll back my edits. This is a tremendously important question in philosophy.

Anytime a question is asked about "us" or about "human" capabilities, it's good to ask the same question more generally. -- Can a cat think about a mouse without using words? Is a cat waiting at the mouse hole thinking about anything? (Is a copper sitting in his car, waiting for a speeding driver?) When a mouse is playing dead - is that a form of language (or at least of intentional deception)?

Some answers on linguistic-relativity

one
two
three


Thinking that all thoughts begin as verbal thought has a bootstrapping problem. Thus: it cannot be the case. It would be better to ask if any thoughts can begin as purely verbal thoughts. I think probably not.

Uh… Can words exist without thought? Clearly not…
Can thoughts exist without words? Clearly…
Duh!

Your question is an empirical question about whether unsymbolized thinking happens. Any consensus among philosophers is of no import to this question; what matters is what neuroscience has revealed.
People and animals have thoughts without using words. This has been validated in humans who have either not developed, or who have lost, the ability to produce language. Even in people who do have the ability to produce language, there is the ability to have unsymbolized thinking.

There are also people who do not have an inner voice - that is, they NEVER hear words in their minds. It's around 10% of the population. It would be interesting to ask them how they "think". As for me I can think both with and without the voice (and thus words). When thinking about what to reply to others (such as writing this comment) I hear words. When solving problems I "see" shapes in my mind - not words.

I personally disagree that it’s “just an empirical question”, but find it much more a problem of conceptual definition or what Carnap called “explication”, which is when you analyze a word to try to unearth what its definition should be. I agree that “consensus” isn’t that interesting here, but I think neuroscience is in too early a stage to claim to be the only field of knowledge worth consulting with at this time. The hard part of the question is defining “language” and “thought” and disentangling their relationship to one another.

It may sound paradoxical, but I would go one step further and say "Even when people believe they are thinking in words, they are not actually doing so. When thinking in words, the thinking that is actually being done is not 'in words'." Suppose it were in words, then the words would be the thinking. Which would be kind of weird - since how would those words (identical to the thinking) then be generated? -- If you're translating a text, in which language would you be thinking? In both? In one of them? Or in neither?

And what about words generating novel thoughts?

@JKusin - Words themselves don't do anything, right? They are just sound waves or ink marks or squiggles on a screen. They need to be perceived and noticed (as differences that could make a difference), read and interpreted by some interpreter, converted into "meanings" (differences that do make a difference). Is this very different from noticing and then following the tracks of an animal that an interpreter might want to find?

Focusing back on possible improvements to the answer: “Your question is just an empirical question about whether unsymbolized thinking happens.” Sure, that’s a nice way to clarify the terms of the question. “What matters is what the neuroscience has revealed.“ Not necessarily, because neuroscience isn’t a complete theory of mind. It hasn’t succeeded in explaining all of consciousness as of right now.

“People and animals have thoughts without using words. This has been validated in humans who have either not developed, or who have lost, the ability to produce language.” This would benefit from a reference, adding detail and evidence to the claim that “People and animals have thoughts without using words.” An important part of this assertion is: “What do you consider to be ‘thoughts’?”. “And even in people who do have the ability to produce language, there is also the ability to have unsymbolized thinking.” This would similarly benefit from a reference.

(I’m trying to be constructive, not critical.)

@mudskipper Symbols themselves don't do anything. But once we endow some set of symbols with some meaning, we then can rearrange and use the symbols in novel ways to create meaning that was inaccessible without them. Think of abstract mathematical ideas that took formal rules to discover and prove as an example, or just a skilled writer conjuring up novel ideas via their sentence constructions.

@JKusin - Yes, of course. Nothing I said disputes that or is incompatible with that. Does it?

@mudskipper At least from my perspective on my qualia, when I "think in words", I can interrupt the words in my mind and still be aware of the meaning the words were going to represent. "Thinking in words" for me is then basically an unconscious pre-abstraction of some sort that seems to aid in internal organization of my thoughts. Maybe that's not literally thinking in words, and perhaps this assumption to follow is incorrect, but I always assumed this sort of internal organizational abstraction of thoughts is what others referred to by the concept.

@Idran - I believe this is an area where people can be surprisingly different (just like some people only discover they are color blind pretty late during adolescence for instance). - But I wonder: Can you really interrupt yourself? Or is your train of (verbal) thought interrupted by something (either a perception or a sudden memory or itch... etc)? Of course you can do so, in a way, if you deliberately set out to do so, but even then -- what made you decide to interrupt yourself at that particular moment then (when you interrupt yourself)?

When I'm biking I don't have to think about moving my legs to pedal. Similarly, when I'm writing (here) the words come by themselves as it were. I can go back and forth and change something -- after I wrote sth and it doesn't completely "feel" "right", but they still keep coming by themselves when I'm "formulating my thoughts".

@mudskipper Oh, that's a good point, I'm not actually sure now that you point it out? Whenever I've tried it to see what would happen, it was with intention, so that is a tangle there. You've given me something to think about. :D

Different philosophers have different views on the question of how thought and language interrelate. According to modern cognitive science, not all thoughts require language, and not all language use requires thoughts. Take playing tennis. Hitting a ball with a racket requires thought, but generally one doesn't think in language or use language to hit the ball. One perceives the ball, and then responds accordingly with one's body. On the other hand, computers use language every day, but it would be difficult to describe even the best computers as thinking, at least in the way the term is applied even to our Great Ape relatives.
Some philosophical positions defend a tighter relationship between thought and language, such as the language of thought hypothesis. For example, Jerry Fodor put forth the position that thought primarily occurs as a language:

The language of thought hypothesis (LOTH), sometimes known as thought ordered mental expression (TOME), is a view in linguistics, philosophy of mind and cognitive science, forwarded by American philosopher Jerry Fodor. It describes the nature of thought as possessing "language-like" or compositional structure (sometimes known as mentalese). On this view, simple concepts combine in systematic ways (akin to the rules of grammar in language) to build thoughts. In its most basic form, the theory states that thought, like language, has syntax.
- Wikipedia

In computer science and AI, this view has traditionally been associated with thinkers like Putnam and Fodor, and found its way into the philosophy of AI as the physical symbol system hypothesis. This is the belief that computer languages are enough to simulate human intelligence, a view labelled by John Haugeland as GOFAI with the emergence of connectionism. More recent cognitive science - what Lakoff calls ‘2nd generation’ - moves in the direction of embodied cognition (SEP) as a requirement for human thought.
What the exact nature of the relationship is still a matter of considerable controversy, and there are many bright thinkers from Dennett to Shea to Chalmers who have different opinions.

This answer provides a really good review of a number of philosophical approaches to the question, which is I think ideally the kind of answer it should get, since it is such a vast and multifaceted question. However, I would support editing the style to be more compact and subtly less conversational, personally.

@JuliusHamilton Well, you're certainly free to edit any answer if you keep in the spirit of the response. :D

tl;dr: Animals can think without words.
I noticed recently that my dog can observe a situation, anticipate what will happen, and autonomously, without being trained, much less receiving a command, act accordingly (in his opinion).
As a concrete example: There is a rock at the shore from which my daughter likes to jump. One day, the dog saw her walking towards it and, after a second or two, went into the water and swam towards it to wait for her below. These are the empirical facts. My interpretation, which is in part based on previous experience and observations of the dog's behaviour, is that he (correctly!) anticipated that she'd jump again, considered that a risky move, and decided to be around, to help if need be.
In my opinion, these mental processes count as "thinking". On the other hand, I doubt he uses words, at least not in the everyday sense of the word (pardon the pun). Although he understands some "signal words" (commands), "rock", "jump", "swim", or "danger" are not among them. So, I'd say he can think without words.
Of course, if we redefine "words" to mean any kind of mental representation---sounds, shapes, smells, memories, emotions, etc.---of anything, including thoughts, the answer is a trivial "No!".

This neither proves the dog was thinking, nor that it didn't use any language. So it's personal and anecdotal.

@tkruse - This question and answer is not about Other Minds. We can never "prove" that a dog (or any other human) is thinking. In other words, asking for a "proof" in this context is asking for some metaphysical piece of evidence that by definition cannot be given. But in actual life (and science) we rely on observation and evidence... IgorF provided pretty clear evidence (and probably has tons more) that his dog was indeed "thinking" (= interpretating observations, making decisions, acting accordingly).

This answer would be better as a comment. It provides valuable context, but ideally, an answer provides more theoretical argumentation, and links the topic to pre-existing philosophical work.

@JuliusHamilton I respectfully disagree: "Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on Philosophy Meta, or in Philosophy Chat". See also https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment


What is the nature of the relationship between language and thought?

This inevitably depends on what we mean by "language" and "thought".
Like Descartes, I think a thought is any event in my mind which I am conscious of.
Because of this definition, it is probably impossible to identify by name every thought we can have. Some seem too elusive, inchoate, evanescent, idiosyncratic etc.
Given this definition, what could be the use of thought? Most plausibly, we have thoughts because some of the behaviours we need to have to survive, prosper and reproduce require thinking. Just walking in the street requires not only perception but also (real-time) thinking. I don't think that this is even controversial.
What is language?
A language, properly speaking, is a conventional system of signs that humans use to convey and share . . . thoughts.
Thoughts are entirely subjective and private. Language is mostly public and objective, although we can also think by using the same language within the privacy of our mind.
Our thoughts develop presumably through the interactions of our neurons. Language develops through the interactions between different people. It seems very unlikely that an isolated individual would bother or even think about developing a language.
Language requires both thoughts (to be conveyed, articulated, expressed etc.), and thinking, because to speak and to understand what other people say is a mental process, only part of which is conscious.
Thoughts do not require language, but it seems very unlikely that an isolated individual could come up on his own with complex abstract ideas. The fact that we use language to convey our thoughts allows the individual to share his or her ideas with other individuals. The result is that at least some thoughts will only occur as a consequence of this interaction.
There is also a sort feedback loop whereby named thoughts can be summoned, get relative prominence over thoughts with no verbal identification, and are more easily memorised.
Language has obvious psychological effects, some of which probably are not obvious, and may not have been identified by psychologists.
Thought is a very old phenomenon. Language is relatively recent.
Thought is intuitive. You don't learn to think.
Language is learnt. Children can pick up any language from their entourage.
The importance of language seems systematically underappreciated.
There is a historical dimension to language, which feeds back into our thoughts. Thinking evolves only because language by nature does and allows thinking to evolve. Humans have much more abstract thoughts today than they could have had in the past, and this mostly because of the rather enormous development of means of (linguistic) communication.
Language undoubtedly allows each of us to develop an understanding of the real world that we probably could not achieve without language. We can still read Aristotle and understand to some extent the thoughts that he had 2,500 years ago. Sometimes, it is even easier to understand Aristotle than to understand our contemporaries.

I would add one more thing to "language". The function of language is not just to share thoughts. Sometimes it is to conceal thoughts or conceal intentions, so to deliberated deceive others. Yet another function would be simply to make others do something (sharing one's intention can be part of that, but is not the main purpose of the speech act). ("Can you please hand me the coffee?". "I can" is a funny answer.) And yet another function is mostly performative (e.g. by saying "I promise (this or that)" I make a promise).

@mudskipper "The function of language is not just to share thoughts". No, as I said, it is also used to convey thoughts, which covers what you say.

Today, most philosophers/cognitive scientists tend to agree that it is possible to think without language, but the way this theory is formulated varies in some specific details (e.g. Carruthers says it is possible, but it is not possible to determine what you are thinking without language).
At the opposite side, there are philosophers like Donald Davidson that affirmed the impossibility of thoughts without language. But the arguments he employed -- appealing to notions such as semantic indeterminacy and thought holism -- are considered weak by the majority of philosophers today. Moreover, contemporary cognitive science already speaks of "concepts" as language-independent mental constructions that can, however, be incremented and overlayed by language. They are forms of representations that track items that assist animal navigation in the world, mostly in terms of recognition, without any need for language.
On a final note, a contemporary philosopher called Wayne Waxman follows a kantian approach to this problem that I find really interesting:

Kant charted a middle course between the extremes of intellectualism and empiricist sensibilism. By recasting the sensibilist theory of ideas in terms of apperception, he brought logical universality into the psyche in the guise of the analytic unity of apperception and, with it, a minimalist conception of logical form as limited to combining AUA-universals and ensuring the a priori unity of the judging subject. Supplemented by reflection, comparison, and abstraction, propositional thought can serve a wide range of purposes in the individual, isolated mind, prior to and independent of the public conventions and institutions that make vernacular language possible. Nevertheless, this purely mental propositional thought, with its paltry twelve logical forms, falls far short of the logical, grammatical, and semantic resources available to speakers of even the most "primitive" vernacular. Language is thus no free rider for Kant: while his sensibilist psychologism may not leave the entire burden of language to the vernacular' as Hume did, it still contrasts fundamentally with intellectualism in leaving it by far the greatest part. -- (Kant's Anatomy of The Intelligent Mind, p.549)


I will present a Kantian response, and then a post-Kantian close.
We are always already in the stuff of language if, like Kant, you utilize the notion of an a priori ordering of thought, namely, rational experience as such under the a priori aegis of the imagination and the understanding. These a priori actions (i.e., syntheses) of our own subjectivity are already in the form of language.
To give one quote, from the Critique of Pure Reason, Transcendental Deduction A version, A125ff:

Actual experience, which is constituted by apprehension, association
(reproduction), and finally recognition of appearances, contains in
recognition.... [the] grounds of the recognition of the manifold, so
far as they concern solely the form of an experience in general, [in]
the categories. Upon them is based not only all formal unity in the
[transcendental] synthesis of imagination, but also, thanks to that
synthesis, all its empirical employment (in recognition, reproduction,
association, apprehension) in connection with the appearances. For
only by means of these fundamental concepts can appearances belong to
knowledge or even to our consciousness, and so to ourselves.

For Kant, the first active synthesis of the manifold of what is given in apprehension (i.e., inner and outer sensibility) happens in the imagination and from there in recognition by the understanding. For Kant, the nature of the rational subject is such that it has always prepared a world which possesses (rational) order that is the empirical seed bed of (rational) human language, as the condition for its possibility, that is, its own experience. To think is to be ringing in language.
So with Kant, we are always already thinking under the total system of rules which language, empirically developed, demands in order for our own essential experience to then be possible. Readied for language and by a kind of language as coding, the world and thought are both ordered rationally a priori:

Thus the order and regularity in the appearances, which we entitle
nature, we ourselves introduce.

Kant links language to the a priori rational ordering of appearances, which constitute experience as such for a rational subject. To be such a subject, and to think, to possess a thought of fact or fancy, is to already bear the fundamental imperatives of language, and, NB, to therefore already be actively pursuing them, due to what is demanded for the possibility of our very subjectivity, our essential "ourselves."
Sometimes Kant uses the word "soul" (Seele) to represent this ne plus ultra of being a subject. But the overarching feature of Kant's model of the subject, it is always a rational subject, and so the imagination is rational in essence in his conception of it.
Just as Plato in the Republic assumes for the sake of his argument, the spirited will (thumos) shall be loyal to reason (Rep. 441a), Kant assumed for his argument, a rational imagination. That is the key pivot of the Kantian subject. Imagination maybe can run free; but a rational imagination -- Kant's quarry -- imagines in rational categories.
If one is not interested in the Kantian model of the subject, his answer as to why thought and language are meet, or if one is not interested in a strictly rational subject, one can quickly change the mood by adopting a Freudian perspective and interject in place of imagination the play (aka, synthesis) of memory.
If I stand at a blackboard and take to thought, my reason is matched by memory. But memory is not bound by categories and in fact memories are often characterized by their resistance to them. Memory, unlike Kant's imagination, is not commanded by order. The Kantian subject has no depth, one can say, and to move the Kantian subject forward, I find it an easy observation that Freud's project was largely to give a voice to that depth, its own language, which speaks, like dreams, other than reason.
I would argue to start with the Kantian subject if you are curious about thought and language and find the Kantian project appealing. Kant summarizes everything tripartite since Plato, and since Freud too is a tripartite thinker, one of the last, you get nicely set up, perspective-wise.

While this does represent heavyweight philosophic teaching, modern science seems to prove it wrong.

@tkruse "modern science seems to prove it wrong." Define it.

See https://mcgovern.mit.edu/2019/05/02/ask-the-brain-can-we-think-without-language/ or other upvoted answers. Most philosophy predates modern neurological research.

That is quite different from saying that X proves Y wrong. Thank you for the effort to share your enthusiasm for science. I am not sure I am even enthusiastic about reason. Which my answer reveals, if you read it closely.

Kant never linked "language to the a priori rational ordering of appearances". The synthesis of recognition is a merely psychological procedure, not a linguistic one, since for Kant concepts are simply psychological representations that incorporate the analytic unity of apperception, and thereby acquire logical universality. Concepts are, therefore, rooted in the individual isolated psyche, quite apart from language, conventions and social infrastructures.

Language is an empirical application of reason for Kant at the very least.

Blocking progress on this question: beginning with language understood as simply a collection of word tokens, and mind understood as simply individual minds- both separated from their environments and how they came to pass in childhood. Children first learn words WITH caregivers and IN situations. Vygotsky theorized that children then develop "thinking" by first talking to themselves while doing something, and then internalizing words through silent recollection. The result would be: no thought/language apart from (first) speaking with others in external situations. Then language and thought get modified further by written language, which prompts the various "separations" that cause so many philosophical problems.

OP : "Have philosophers come to a consensus about the relationship between language and thinking?"
Here are a few quotes from Heidegger's Being & Time (H.160-161) where he addresses understanding and language. His approach is that one important mode of 'being' (i.e. existing alive) is our collective culture (the mode called 'being-with').  The way we transmit ideas between each other is talking, with language. So it is very fundamental. One needs language to learn and develop.
But I would agree that a geometry problem for instance, could be solved by wordless intuition.  One would need language to learn geometry in the first place though.

¶ 34. Being-there and Discourse. Language
The fundamental existentialia which constitute the Being of the
"there", the disclosedness of Being-in-the-world, are states-of-mind
and understanding. In understanding, there lurks the possibility of
interpretation—that is, of appropriating what is understood. ... The
existential-ontological foundation of language is discourse or
talk.1 ...
Discourse is existentially equiprimordial with state-of-mind and understanding. The intelligibility of something has always been
articulated, even before there is any appropriative interpretation of
it. Discourse is the Articulation  of intelligibility. Therefore it
underlies both interpretation and assertion. That which can be
Articulated in interpretation, and thus even more primordially in
discourse, is what we have called "meaning". ... The intelligibility
of Being-in-the-world—an intelligibility which goes with a
state-of-mind—expresses itself as discourse. ...
The way in which discourse gets expressed is language.1 ...
As an existential state in which Dasein is disclosed, discourse is
constitutive for Dasein's existence. ...
Discoursing or talking is the way in which we articulate
'significantly' the intelligibility of Being-in-the-world. Being-with
belongs to Being-in-the-world, which in every case maintains itself in
some definite way of concernful Being-with-one-another.



The limits of my language are the limits of my world
Wittgenstein

Anyone who truly groks this must have an instantaneous horror reaction as though to an interminable sentence to an invisible prison — the prison of my language.
But as we digest the unpleasantness of the “sentence” we also begin to see it is inexorable:

I cannot speak my thought without thinking my speech
Roland Barthes

But we can take a moment on this: Must I think in a “speech-y” way?
Here a four-way classification of communication from Hindu philosophy comes in handy.
Vak, literally speech but by implication all communication is said to be possible at four levels

Vaikhari — uttered words, verbiage
Madhyama — verbal thoughts
Pashyanti — insight
Para — Transcendence

Clearly Wittgenstein's law is absolute at level 1 and as good as absolute at 2. Around 3 it begins to weaken and thin out; at 4 it's obviously false.
On the flip side, transcendence is by definition out of reach so that is in a sense useless. But we can have more or less insight. And as we cultivate that we become correspondingly less linguistically bound.
See Bilingualism is cognitively advantageous
and Bilingualism statistically delays Alzheimer by 4 years
So one way to imperate that into an effective praxis is to make oneself multilingual.
Sapir Whorf
The Sapir-Whorf hypothesis — that language can shape thought — also known as linguistic relativity has many different facets.
Following is from here
Egocentricism
English is inherently egocentric to an extent that is unimaginable... until we experience non egocentric languages
The basic way an English speaker orients themself is left,right,front,back.
Whose left, right, front, back?
Why mine of course!
Now consider the Australian language Guugu Ymithirr.
It has no left, right, front, back, only North, South, East, West
The result is the Guugu Ymithirr speakers always have an “internal compass” — they always know* where is N,S,E,W.
Absolute Pitch
Absolute pitch — the ability to tell the exact pitch of a note — is rare in western countries even among musicians. The chinese have a much higher incidence of it. And Chinese is a tone language
Truth and Evidence
The Matses people of Nuevo San Juan, Peru always speak in terms of evidence:
For example, if you are asked, “How many apples do you have?” then a Matses speaker might answer, “I had four apples last time I checked my fruit basket.” Regardless of how sure the speaker is that they still have four apples, if they can’t see them, then they have no evidence what they are saying is true—for all they know, a thief could have stolen three of the apples, and the information would be incorrect.
Matses has one set of verb endings for the source of the knowledge and another, separate way of conveying how true, or valid the information is, and how certain they are about it. Interestingly, there is no way of denoting that a piece of information is hearsay, myth, or history. Instead, speakers impart this kind of information as a quote, or else as being information that was inferred within the recent past.
Theology and Metaphysics
While theology/metaphysics may at first blush seem far away from Sapir-Whorf, the following examples may help to a rethink:
God
Think of the endless arguments that interminable go on out here between theists — there is God vs the atheists — there is no God.
Now consider the native American perspective: God is a verb.
Does the atheist-theist argument even subsist if God goes from being a noun, "a-guy-in-the-sky" to a verb, a mode of being?
Holy Spirit
The holy spirit in Christianity is co-equal to God the Father and the Son. In Greek the word is pneuma.
Note how inexorably "spiritual" and therefore unreal spirit is as compared to pneuma which evokes the sense of breath.
Diehard materialists/atheists may doubt the spiritual, do they doubt their own breath?
Nietzsche

You say you don't believe in God, yet you believe in grammar

Consider the above statement in the light of examples of which the above are only a small sample

It's not clear whether this is an answer or just more questions and comments on the topic.

@Rushi - It's unclear to me why you mention absolute pitch in this context. It's true that more speakers with a tone language as first language have absolute pitch, but this just indicates that learning this is probably (partially) related to a critical period in a child's language learning (and to the fact that in the West very young kids hardly ever get deliberate extensive exposure to classical music). But what does it have to do with language and thought?

@mudskipper Isn't absolute pitch a specific  cognitive ability? And if you admit to the fact that some languages conduce toward statistically significant increase in that ability, then it's a strong case for Sapir Whorf isn't it? I don't see what classical music has to do with it. In particulara european culture child brought up with a strong classical music background is unlikely to have absolute pitch.

I see - you define "thinking" as "having cognitive ability". I don't quite see how in this case it strengthens Sapir-Whorf. It seems a rather trivial convergence: the same (or a very similar) skill is trained in distinguishing musical pitch and in distinguishing tones in a tone language. Absolute pitch can still be learned somewhat (and with great difficulty) by adults, btw. (Classical music is relevant because it generally is far more complex than popular music. A child also needs to be exposed as early as possible + trained in solfege.)

The one thing I like about this answer is that -- so far -- it's the only answer that it underlines the importance of looking at actual natural languages and how they work (!) It's seems insane to me that people believe they can understand "thought" and "language" without making their linguist's hands dirty, so to speak, and trying to actually understand what is happening in very different languages... As if just a bit of logic, semantics and introspection could tell us much or anything about this.

@mudskipper  Yes. There is a joke I think from Lera Boroditsky that the monolingual linguists doubt Sapir Whorf; the multilingual ones laugh. More seriously it's an etic-emic question.

@Rushi Reading your intro about Plato Sapir Ramana my comment . I think therefore I exist is wrong. I exist therefore I think

@quanity In a sane world that would be a trite and tautological observation. However because we (western thought) is messed up by 4 centuries cartesian thinking it seems profound

@mudskipper I changed the absolute pitch link. Hope this one makes the point better

We know empirically that there are people without internal monolog.
The fact that people can understand and evaluate a situation, create a plan of action and execute it without using words is a strong indicator that something that we would see as "thought" occurs, in the absence of words.
Note that this is distinct from purely instinctive actions.
Now depending on how exactly you define the word "thought", you might disqualify this. However, if you narrow your definition down that much I believe you've created a tautology and essentially defined "thought" as something that uses words.

It depends on what you mean by "thought".  If you mean something that originates from your mind, then no.  But this is not the sole source of thought.  The heart has a center which pushes thought into action.  These proto-thoughts have no words, but they carry an intuition about what they're about ("I'm hungry." "I'm about to lose my job." Whatever.).
These feelings are distinct in character so seem similar to a thought activation, but they are not.  This is part of the mind-body dualism to keep you sane.  Those proto-thoughts arise just before the brain activates come from other parts of your own genome and its vast experience (or the collective unconscious, if you wish).

+1 though I'd distinguish "heart" from "solar plexus" even though they're quite close. In more psychological lingo, there's conscious subconscious and superconscious. In Hindu philosophy these "pre thoughts" are called vasana literally smell, idiomatically seed thoughts. The very last verse of the Ramayana is Give me that love for Ram which a glutton has fir food, and a debauch has for woman. IOW the poet asks for pre-intellectual, pre-verbal, cellular love for God

A useful definition, also used by Kant in his philosophy, equates

to think = operating with concepts, propositions, conclusions (German: Begriff, Aussage, Schluss).

According to this definition:

Can you think anything without word? No, because no concepts without
words.

Can you think any word without thought? No, because thinking without
thoughts is a contradictio in adjecto.

Which comes first word or thought? Words are first, because thinking
requires concepts and these require words.


Choosing a different definition of “to think” may imply different answers.
Added: Thinking according to the definition above does not presuppose the ability to speak.

+1 "Choosing a different definition of “to think” may imply different answers." There's the rub! Otherwise, one is left with the dilemma of until a child learns their first word, they do not think. That seems suspect.

@JD Which definition of "to think" would apply also to children before they learn their first words?

Does a relationship exist between sound the experience of sound,  and an associated visual experience of that sound to relate to an action from the sound giver. I would suggest this as a basis of language. Once this reaction exists you base your thought upon sounds which usually reduce to words although they may have been initially grunts which developed into nore sophisticated syntax.

It is obvious that you are in the 90% of people with an inner voice. There's 10% of the population who don't have an inner voice and therefore think without words. For me I have 2 ways of thinking - if I need to reply to people (such as writing this down) I think with words. If I'm solving a problem there are no words in my mind. Instead I see shapes - I see the problem in my mind. I don't "describe" the problem because describing is using words, instead I "render" the problem.

When I deal with a packing problem, I see object shapes and fitting solutions.  And see fitting failures.  the mental space objects, and object interactions, are concepts.  The effort to fit is a proposition.  The success/failure for packing is a conclusion.  Yes, thinking can be done without words.

@Dcleve Could you please give a definition of "to think" which fits your example. Not each mental process is thinking. Thanks.

Jo Wheler-- I used your definition in this answer:  "operating with concepts, propositions, conclusions".  Igor F.'s dog also is clearly thinking., per that same definition

@Decleve Mental space objects, object interactions = concepts(!); effort to fit =  proposition(!), success/failure = conclusion(!): I am in doubt that Kant would have agreed.

@JoWehler - Why would we care if Kant would have agreed? We know a lot more about "thinking" and language now than Kant ever knew and the problem is not to arrive at an agreed-upon interpretation of the pretty dubious ratiocinations of Kant...

@mudkipper IMO Decleve's interpretation of the three terms concept, proposition, conclusion, is not covered by Kants definition of "to think". And I made Kant's definition the basis of my answer. - Possibly a different definition, e.g., on the basis of present neurosccience or philosophy of the mind, may reply with a different answer.

@JoWehler - The tortoise would counter this: "That's whay you say. But what would Kant have said?"

@mudskipper What would Kant say?? Oooo! how my ideas have ossified in 200 years

For Kant, concepts are representations that incorporate the analytic unity of apperception -- the "I think" --, and thereby acquire logical universality. This is a merely psychological operation: therefore, concepts don't require language or conventions.
